# How to call AWS EC2 instance endpoint with HTTPS instead of HTTP

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-ec2

I have an Angular client (v14) that needs to call a spring boot application that run on an AWS EC2 instance. My angular app is hosted on Firebase. My Angular client is deployed under HTTPS so when I do http calls in Angular with something like that :

httpclient.get(http://myPublicDnsAdress:8080/myApiPath)

I have that error:

```html
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mywebsiteurl.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://ec2-15-188-59-23.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/activity/random?numberOfActivities=10'. This request has 
been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

I know I need to call my EC2 instance with HTTPS instead of HTTP. Hence my Angular calls would be :

httpclient.get(**https**://myPublicDnsAdress:8080/myApiPath)

Instead of:

httpclient.get(**http**://myPublicDnsAdress:8080/myApiPath)

This is where i'm stuck, I don't know how to do it or what is the best option.

Note: I'm new to AWS and I'd like to avoid setting up something that will we cost money like load balancer and so on. But if it is not possible I will do so.

Thank you very much in advance for you help.

Answer (score 1):

The error is clear. You **can't mix** https and http. The error clear writes that you are using http to access:

```
http://ec2-15-188-59-23.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com:8080
```

You have to get proper public ssl certification for your instance as well as your **own domain**, and setup https for the instance. You can't use https with `ec2-15-188-59-23.eu-west-3.compute.amazonaws.com` as this is AWS's domain (not yours). You can only setup valid public SSL for your own domain.

Comment: It is not compulsory to use public sertificates. It is possible to generate  self signed SSL certficates and use them with EC2 instances. Certainly it is a good practice to limit the use of self signed certificates to development and use public certificates for production workloads.

Comment: @MarkoEskola No modern browser will accept self-signed certificate, just like they do not accept mixing https and http.

Comment: They actually do and self-signed certificates are used all the time in development. Even AWS EC2 tutorials cover this use case: (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2022.html). The browser throws a warning for the first time but this is a normal behavior.   And I have to repeat myself: self-signed certificates should not be used in production. They will encrypt transmission but do not offer a proof of identity.

Comment: @MarkoEskola I would suggest making your own answer to OP's question. Then you can provide more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Make the spring boot application to use secure HTTPS instead of normal HTTP.

I am not familiar with Spring Boot but there is a tutorial with a github repository at:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-https-self-signed-certificate

It teaches how to use Spring Boot with self-signed certificates in development but certainly in production valid public certificates should be used.